# neo4j ha cluster failure at node launch

Tags: neo4j, high-availability, vsphere

i've been following this tutorial https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/highly-available-cluster/ to set a 3 nodes ha cluster on 3 different vm on vsphere and i'm experiencing some issue when it comes to launch the node. (./bin/neo4j start)
I check the log and i got something  like this

```
        2018-02-28 16:57:17.117+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.9 ========
        2018-02-28 16:57:17.188+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-02-28 16:57:18.629+0000 INFO  Write transactions to database disabled
2018-02-28 16:57:19.054+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2018-02-28 16:57:19.084+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2018-02-28 16:57:20.539+0000 INFO  Attempting to join cluster of [10.2.48.87:5001, 10.2.48.88:5001, 10.2.48.89:5001]
2018-02-28 16:57:50.665+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@52405ea8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@52405ea8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@52405ea8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:215)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@52405ea8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:207)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /opt/neo4j-enterprise-3.2.9/data/databases/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:209)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$0(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin@5210d51b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Conversation-response mapping:
{1/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='1/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}
    at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachineProxyFactory$ResponseFuture.get(StateMachineProxyFactory.java:315)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.joinByConfig(ClusterJoin.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.start(ClusterJoin.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 13 more
2018-02-28 16:57:50.666+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

I don't understand it,can somebody tell me more about it. Like you can see i work with Neo4j 3.2.9 and it's working fine when i'm launching it in standalone on each machine.

Comment: clustering is on enterprise edition only

Comment: i'm using the trial of the entreprise edition

Answer (score 0):

"Write transactions to database disabled" 
MAY mean that no MASTER can be elected.
Can each instance reach the others ?
Are the IDs (in neo4j.conf) different ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. In my case the IDs are different.

Comment: @Mishu , Paul Maksud  can each server reach the others ?

Comment: yes they could reach each other , i solved the problem momentarily by launching all the node as simultaneously as i could.